# Huge hdd load when creating keys

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've configured the -keypool=n parameter to create a lot of keys at once.
During the generation, the hdd has a lot of IO, why?

Comment: It may be using the IO activity as a source of entropy for the PRNG to generate your keys. Not sure if this would actually cause it to activate so to speak but it is a possability.. if I can confirm this il write a full answer..